Is there a way to conserve the same colors on two different chord diagrams?
i would like to conserve the sames colors between my first chord graph (Genus of trees + symbiosis Order) and my second chord graph (family of trees + symbiosis Order). The symbiosis order are not changing so i'm trying to conserve the same colors for them between those two graphs.
adjacencyData <- with(Symb, table(Ordre_symbiose, Genre_essence))

set.seed(2)
par(bg = "grey90")
chordDiagram(adjacencyData, transparency = 0.5, 
             annotationTrack = "grid", 
             preAllocateTracks = 1
             )

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim <- get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim <- get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.index <- get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1], sector.index, facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, cex = 0.6, adj = c(0, 0.5))
}, bg.border = NA)

I've tried to use set.seed() but some colors are changing while others are not.
Here Russulales at left is blue
Here Russulales is purple

Can you provide some data?
